# How to store join query data and retrieve using foreach loop from master layout page in asp.net mvc

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-framework-6

I am new in asp.net mvc. I am trying to build role wise dynamic menu show in the view page. Each user can have multiple role.
I have a join query like:

My Controller looks like with join query:

```
 var query= (from rMPageMap in db.RoleModulePageMaps
                                 join userRole in db.UserRoleMaps
                                 on rMPageMap.RoleId equals 
                                 join roleMaster in db.RoleMasters
                                 on rMPageMap.RoleId equals roleMaster.Id
                                 join modMaster in db.ModuleMaster
                                on rMPageMap.ModuleId equals modMaster.Id
                                 join sModMaster in db.SubModuleMasters
                           on rMPageMap.SubModuleId equals sModMaster.Id
                                 join pMaster in db.PageMasters
                                 on rMPageMap.PageId equals pMaster.Id
                               where (userRole.UserId == appuser.Id &)
                                 select new
                                 {

                                     rMPageMap.RoleId,
                                     rMPageMap.PageMaster.Name,
                                     roleMaster.Id,
                                     roleName = roleMaster.Name,
                                     modId = modMaster.Id,
                                     moduleName = modMaster.Name,
                                     subModuleId = sModMaster.Id,
                                     subModuleName = sModMaster.Name,
                                     pageId = pMaster.Id,
                                     pageName = pMaster.Name,
                                     parentPageId = pMaster.ParentPageId,
                                     rMPageMap.AddData,
                                     rMPageMap.EditData,
                                     rMPageMap.ViewData,
                                     rMPageMap.DeleteData,
                                     rMPageMap.ShowInDashBoard,
                                     rMPageMap.ShowInMenu
                                 });
Session["rolemodulepage"] = query;
```

I find the values in the session while debugging. but i can not retrieve data from this using foreach loop in layout page.
Here is my view page that i try ro retrieve but does not work.

View Page:

```
  @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
  {
  var sessionVar = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["rolemodulepage"];

  foreach(var i in sessionVar) // error
  {
      @i.... // error 
  }
// So here how to retrieve data from session using foreach loop. I tried but does not work. Pls help. If you have some resource for dynamically mane show in view page pls share with me.
```

Can anyone explain that how to do it using showing dynamic menu by role based user in master layout page. Wihout login none can enter the site, pls explain with examples so that i can understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your generating a collection of anonymous objects which you cannot use in a view. Create a view model and pass that model to the view.

Comment: Can u help me...how to do that??? or any hints..

Comment: Create a class with each of those properties and use `select new yourModel { RoleId = rMPageMap.RoleId, .....` etc. (your model will be `IEnumerable<yourModel>`)

Comment: ok then how to use in view to retrieve data by using foreach loop??

Comment: Your controller will have `return View(model);` and in the view - `@model IEnumerable<yourModel>` and then simply `@foreach(var item in Model) { <div>@item.RoleId</div> ....` etc But why are you using `Session` and why are your using `Request.IsAuthenticated` in the view?

Comment: i want to use in the master layout page that's why, i am using session?? in master layout page how can i use without defining @model IEnumerable<yourMode‌​l>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121157/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user267019).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query is generating a collection of anonymous objects which you cannot access in the view. Create a view model containing the properties you need and project your query into it, for example

```
public class MenuVM
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string PageMasterName { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

and then modify the query to

```
var query = (from rMPageMap in db.RoleModulePageMaps
             ....
             where (userRole.UserId == appuser.Id &)
             select(new MenuVM()
             {
                RoleId = rMPageMap.RoleId,
                PageMasterName = rMPageMap.PageMaster.Name,
                ....
             }).AsEnumerable()
```

;

and then in the view you can cast the `Session` value and loop through it

```
var sessionVar = HttpContext.Current.Session["rolemodulepage"] as IEnumerable<MenuVM>;
if (sessionVar  null)
{
    foreach(var i in sessionVar)
    {
        ....
```

However, as this is for generating a menu in a layout, I suggest you create move the code to a child action only method that returns a strongly typed partial view, for example in say `CommonController`

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult Menu()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return null;
    }
    // Check if the session variable exists and if not, generate the query
    // and add the result to session
    return PartialView("_Menu", query);
}
```

and the `_Menu.cshtml` view would be

```
@model IEnumerable<MenuVM>
@foreach (var i in Model)
{
    ....
}
```

and in the layout, use

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Common"); }
```

to generate the html for the menu.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stephen Mueche, First way i have tried and it works nicely and i will apply second way.....thanks again...